How do I fix the buggy kernel affecting my keyboard operation?
I am running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on Linux in a custom-built 64-bit desktop tower.  My keyboard keeps cutting out at intermittent and random times.  When this happens I cannot type letters or numbers other than 0.  Typing letter keys generates symbols like #,$,%, and others.
I've read several comments that state there is a buggy kernel.  Unfortunately, using ddgr to ask the question only provides a few lines of the complete answers and protocols how to fix the issue.
I would appreciate a reply with a solution for fixing the affected kernels, or a link to a reply containing that information.
Thank you for your kind consideration.
Keyboards in use:
1.Gigabyte: GK Force-K7.  Purchase in 2015.  I don't know how to find the kernel number.
32.Redragon Deimos K599-KRS.  Purchased in 2021. Don't know kernel.

Keyboard make, model, age - and kernel version ?

If you think it is a bug, report the bug.

To get the kernel version on Linux, you can use the command uname -r in your terminal.
also kernel is a part of Linux not specific to the keyboard maybe you confused it with "driver" but even so keyboards usually don't need custom drivers.
If you are using an AMD cpu several of their motherboards where known to have usb issues that were fixed by updating the motherboards bios.

Thank you for the information. Using the command you suggested, the kernel number as 6.8.0-48-generic. The computer is, in fact, running an AMD FX-8350 8-core processor. The motherboard (MSI 970A-G43) has been updated once, but it has been several years since the bios was updated. As noted, the computer is a custom gaming build.  @Hannu
